# Android TextToSpeech UtteranceProgressListener out of sync after changing SpeedRate

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm using Android's `TextToSpeech`. I am also highlighting text as the words are spoken, I am doing this with the help of `UtteranceProgressListener` and it's method `onRangeStart(String utteranceId, int start, int end, int frame)`.

The problem is that when the speech rate is changed on my `TextToSpeech` object, the utterance progress listener does not account for this change and continues to execute `onRangeStart` at the same rate as the default speech rate.

If I set a speech rate of `0.5f` then the `onRangeStart` method will execute as if the speech rate were `1.0f` causing the text to be highlighted out of sync with the spoken words. Maybe this is a bug?

Here is my code:

```
speaker.setSpeechRate(0.5f);
speaker.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStart(String s) { }
    @Override
    public void onDone(String s) { }
    @Override
    public void onError(String s) { }

    @Override
    public void onRangeStart(String utteranceId, int start, int end, int frame) {
        super.onRangeStart(utteranceId, start, end, frame);
        tarAdapter.highlightWord(currentSentenceIndex, start, end);
    }
});
```

Comment: Same problem. Have no problems with it on google emulator. But on real device (tested on huawei) i faced the same issue.

Comment: True. Same issue here too. Were you able to find a workaround for this?

Comment: Nope, never found a workaround :( @Sriram